# I need information and in which language it is coded, help me if you have time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display my product like this : with selection step by step
https://www.wefix.net/pages/marques?type=phone

I don't now how to do it, is this javascript and PHP or jQuery and PHP ? How it's called ? if somebody have time to help, I would be grateful.

Comment: If you think the language is important here, you won't get far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the link you have mentioned. By inspecting, it looks like it is built in a .Net framework using Shopify. They have also used jQuery in it.

If you want to build a web application, there are many options are available to build a web application. Like you can use .Net MVC, PHP, Python, Angular, React, etc.

All the languages have their own pros and cons. You should select the option based on your requirements and which is less complex as per your expertise.

Payment gateway integration and designing can be done as per your requirement in all the languages. So, that can not be a barrier to select a language.

Comment: ok, I'll look into it, thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [steps left](https://ui-patterns.com/patterns/StepsLeft) pattern and can be achieved in pure html and css.
[Here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/EKr4D) is an example using bootstrap (You do not need Bootstrap for this).